# Recursively reverse a linkedlist (code in Stanford CSed library) explanation

Tags: recursion, linked-list, reverse

My recursion skill is pretty rusty. I've been thinking about this problem and searched the forum for a long time but still cannot understand. Right now I'm looking at the recursively reverse a linked list code from Stanford CS ed library.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

struct Node {
  int x;
  struct Node *next;
};

void Reverse(struct Node ** headRef){
    struct Node* first;
    struct Node* rest;

    if(*headRef==NULL)
       return;

    first= *headRef;
    rest= first->next;  

    if(rest==NULL)
        return; 

    Reverse(&rest);
    printf("Rest%d\n", (rest)->x); // I added this line to print rest
    first->next->next=first;
    first->next=NULL;
    *headRef=rest;
}

void printList(struct Node* head){

    if(!head)
       return;
    else{
       printf("%d ", head->x);
       printList(head->next);   
    }
}

void main(){
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node * node1= (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node * node2= (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node * node3= (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node * node4= (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head= node1;
    node1->next=node2;
    node1->x=1;
    node2->x=2;
    node3->x=3;
    node4->x=4;
    node2->next=node3;
    node3->next=node4;
    node4->next=NULL;
    Reverse(&head);
}
```

Now suppose I have a linked list 1->2->3->4. What I cannot understand is the last line, which will set the headRef to 4 eventually, I think it should set the headRef to 2. I tried to execute the function and it printed out:

> 4
>   4
>   4

for the variable rest.

However, if I commented the last line in the the Reverse function out, it still reversed the list but would print

> 4
>   3
>   2.

The second result I can understand, but the first one seemed quite confusing. Does the statement "*headRef=rest" do any thing to the variable rest? What does it keep pointing to 4?

Also, if I pass *headRef instead of **headRef (last line is not commented out), it would print the result

> 4
>   3
>   2

too.

Could anyone please explain to me what happened in the memory? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

Before the recursive call to `Reverse` we have:

```
first---|  
        |  
        v  
        1->2->3->4->NULL
           ^
           |
           |
  rest------
```

After the recursive call to `Reverse` we have:

```
first---|
        |
        v
        1->2<-3<-4
           |     ^
           v     |
         NULL    |
  rest------------
```

Now we need to fix `2->NULL` to `2->1` by `first->next->next=first`.

```
first---|
        |
        v
        1<-2<-3<-4
        |  ^     ^
        |--|     |
                 |
  rest------------
```

Now we need to fix `1->2` to `1->NULL` by `first->next=NULL`.

```
first---|
        |
        v
  NULL<-1<-2<-3<-4
                 ^
                 |
                 |
  rest------------
```

Finally  `*headRef=rest` so that `*headRef` will point to `4` instead of to `1`.

Comment: I think you just talked about the last step...what I don't understand is on your second diagram, why does rest point to 4? When the last recursive call returns and starts to rewind, isn't it pointing to null, then 4, then 3, then 2? Could you explain more in detail? Thank you!

Comment: We start by assuming that Reverse is doing its job. Now notice, in the second diagram, how after the recursive call to Reverse, rest is pointing to 4 instead of to 2. This "magic" was done by *headRef=rest.

Comment: ok...so what does *headRef= rest do to change what rest points to? Thanks

Comment: @user1640669 We start by assuming `Reverse` does what it supposed to be doing. Reversing the list. Now, it doesn't change any global variables, but it does receive its argument pointer *by reference*. So it may alter it. Looking at the last line, it does indeed alter it. So for `ptr->2->3->4->NULL`, after calling `Reverse(&ptr)`, let's assume that now `ptr->4->3->2->NULL`. Now, checking what it does next, shows it indeed makes `2` point to `1`, and then `1` to `NULL`. So it does indeed reverse the argument list `1->2->3->4->NULL`. Wait, it must alter the argument itself! & it does, inLastLine.

Comment: @user1640669 (contd.) so now, `ptr->1->2->3->4->NULL`. Next, we need to check end cases: the `NULL` list and the singleton list. We check it does OK on those, too. If so, end of proof. `*headRef=rest` does not change what `rest` points too. That's over and done with. It changes what `*headRef` points to.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is as because the recursive call passes the ***address of rest to the local variable headRef***, when each recursive call returns, the statement *headRef=rest already changes the address of rest pointer for the statements coming next in the execution flow.

For the linked list 1->2->3->4 :

Let us assume 1 is stored in address 100, 2 in address 200, 3 in address 300 and 4 in address 400.

***PART 1:*** 
the call Reverse(&rest)  [rest points to address 400]

first = 400
rest = NULL

as rest is NULL the execution returns to the point after Reverse(400) call

***PART 2:***
Here first = 300 and rest = 400
after execution of first->next->next=first and first->next=NULL

we have *headRef=rest [rest points to 400]

but this headRef was passed an address of rest=300. So now already for the next step in execution,
rest points to 400.

***PART 3:***
Now execution returns to the point after Reverse(300) call

But during forward call [first was 200 and rest was 300] and during return [rest = 400]. **HERE'S THE TRICK!!!**

after execution of first->next->next=first and first->next=NULL

we have *headRef=rest [rest points to 400]

but this headRef was passed an address of rest=200. So now already for the next step in execution,
rest points to 400.

***PART 4:***
Now execution returns to the point after Reverse(200) call

But during forward call [first was 100 and rest was 200] and during return [rest = 400].

after execution of first->next->next=first and first->next=NULL

we have *headRef=rest [rest points to 400]

and as because this is the initial call, the function returns with *headRef having 400 value.

**JOB DONE!**